# Is it possible to see why my backup with adb is not working?

Tags: adb, backup, google-play-games, samsung-galaxy-s-20

I play some games by a developer and there is no cloud save so most players would use adb to back up and move their save files. Lately though when trying to back up the game, it's just producing a 1kb file, which from my understanding, usually means that they have backup allowed set to disabled. However, in the game's discord I asked about this and the developer says that the allow backup flag is still set to true.

Is there any way on my end that I can see why the backup isn't working as expected? The command I'm using for backup is:

```
adb backup -f "C:\myPath\backup.ab" com.default.name
```

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S20+ 5G (SM-G986U) that has **not** been rooted. Thanks!

Comment: You should name the real package name of the game you want to backup. Even if backup is allowed on modern devices adb will fail if the app uses a certain targetPlatform. Which means that adb backup will not work for most of your apps as you phone has Android 12 or even 13.

Comment: I think it does @Robert. Sounds like adb backup just isn't possible anymore on newly updated apps. That's a shame, but thank you!

Comment: you can backup with Samsung's [transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.easyMover) app. or ask the developer of the app for [android:debuggable](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#adb-backup-restrictions) (as linked by @Robert)